# Consider numbers of the type $n=2^m+1$. Prove that such an n is prime only if $n=F_K$ for some $ k \in N$, where $F_k$ is a Fermat Prime.

Tags: number-theory

1. Consider numbers of the type $n=2^m+1$. Prove that such an $n$ is prime only if $n=F_K$ for some $ k \in N$, where $F_k$ is a Fermat Prime.
2. Consider numbers of the type $n=a^m-1$ where $a>1$ is a natural number. Prove that such an $n$ is prime only if $n=M_p$ for p-prime, where $M_p$ is a Mersennt Prime.

I do not understand what the question is asking me for. Can I get some clarification?

Answer (score 1):

For the first one: if $t$ is odd, then the polynomial $x^t+1$ can be factorised into a product of two polynomials with integer coefficients:
$$x^t+1=(x+1)(x^{t-1}-x^{t-2}+\cdots-x+1)\ .$$
Now suppose that $2^m+1$ is prime, and let $t$ be an odd factor of $m$.  Writing $m=st$, we have from above that
$$2^m+1=(2^s)^t+1=(2^s+1)\ \hbox{times an integer}\ .$$
Since $2^m+1$ is prime, $2^s+1$ can only be equal to $1$ or $2^m+1$.  The first is clearly impossible, so $2^s+1=2^m+1$, so $s=m$, so $t=1$.

What all this proves is that if $2^m+1$ is prime, then $m$ has no odd factor except $1$.  The only values of $m$ for which this is true are powers of $2$, say $m=2^k$, and so
$$2^m+1=2^{2^k}+1=F_k\ .$$

The second problem is quite similar, starting with the factorisation
$$x^t-1=(x-1)(x^{t-1}+x^{t-2}+\cdots+x+1)$$
for any integer $t$.  Give it a try.

Comment: The OP was merely asking for clarification of the *question* itself, while you are giving generous hints on the *answer*.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you're being asked to show that if $n = 2^m + 1$ is prime, then $n$ must be a Fermat prime - i.e. $n$ is of the form $n = 2^{2^k} + 1$ for some $k$. So you need to show that if $n$ is prime, then $m$ is a power of 2.

In the second case, you're being asked to show that if $n = a^m - 1$ is prime, then $n$ must be a Mersenne prime - i.e. $n$ is of the form $n = 2^{p} - 1$ for some prime $p$. So you need to show that if $n$ is prime, then $a = 2$ and $m$ is prime.